# Function definiton with read is blocking the shell

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to use the following function definition in Bash for setting session-wise git-environment variables. If I source this, my Bash blocks, I can only kil it with CTRL+D and then I got a unusable shell back (no commands possible). I guess, something with the read is blocking. The original version even had a "while true; do" in it, but that was even worse wreaking havoc the CPU.
So, two questions arise:

1. How can I reach the goal of having this function working properly?
2. Why does the problem pop up when only defining the function, but not calling it?

   ```
   function git() {
       echo "Running BETTER git..."
       if [ -z "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" ]; then
           echo -n "Git User: "
           read -e UNAME
           if [ "$UNAME" == "user1" ] -o [ "$UNAME" == "user2" ]; then
               echo "Hello $UNAME, you will be set as committer for this git session"
           else
               echo "Invalid User"
           fi
           GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$UNAME
           export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
           GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$UNAME@company.com
           export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
           GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
           export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
           GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
           export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
       fi
       echo "  using git user: $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME / $GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
       /usr/bin/git "$@"
   }
   ```

Comment: Can't reproduce that.

Comment: You also have a syntax error: `if [ "$UNAME" = user1 ] || [ "$UNAME" = user2 ]`; . `-o` is an (obsolete) operator that is intended to be used *inside* `[ ... ]`. However, consider whether having `git` prompt you for name for *every* command is a good idea. In particular, none of this applies to `git branch` which you are trying to run every time you display your prompt.

Comment: Yeah, when something is not reproducable, it often is the user's environment, which in my case was the problem's source (see my own answer below).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to wrong syntax, chepner. The point, why I need session-wise user-settings is, that we work with a technical user for that repo and we need to discern the committing users more easily. The script is intended to be called only once for a session (after that, the environment variable is exported).

Comment: Also, you have a policy issue, not a technical problem. If I didn't trust the users to configure their environment properly before running `git`, I wouldn't trust them to use this function, which is easily bypassed: the user can run `command git` or `/usr/bin/git` directly, or the user can give `GIT_COMMITER_NAME` any bogus non-empty value. Another error: whether they enter a valid name or not, you *still* use it to set the values of the other environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just asking the 2nd question has brought myself to the problem's root: Why is just the definition of the function causing troubles? Because git actually **is** called in my environment:
Changing

```
export PS1=$Color_Off'$(git branch &>/dev/null;\
```

into

```
export PS1=$Color_Off'$(/usr/bin/git branch &>/dev/null;\
```

is solving the issue.
$PS1 is evaluated on every command in the bash, so on every prompt, a git command is issued, thus calling my defined function.

EDIT: I also had to replace all occurrences of "git " with "/usr/bin/git " in my /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt. Now I can alias "git" with that function and it works properly.

Comment: You can also use `/usr/bin/git` in the prompt. That would execute the binary, not the function.